# How to describe the 2D region bounded by a closed curve?

Tags: general-topology, vector-analysis

Let C be some closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How would you describe the set $D$ which represents the region bounded by $C$ as an expression of $C$ using set notation. For instance, if $C$ were a circle of radius 1 centered at the origin, it  could be written in set theory notation as $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid{}x^2+y^2=1\}$. Ultimately, I'm hoping for a rigorous way to define what the set $D$ in Green's theorem ($\oint_C{\vec{F}\cdot{}d\vec{r}}=\iint_D{(\nabla\cdot{}\vec{F})}{dA}$) is as some set theory expression of $C$.

Comment: In your particular case it is $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2 <1\}$ (or $\le$ if you want the region to be closed). In general, you probably cannot write it explicitly and just have to say that $D$ is the region enclosed by $C$. Normally however, you would have it the other way round and define $C$ as the boundary of $D$. If $D$ is open this is $C=\overline{D}\backslash D$.

Comment: @epiliam That is fair. I guess my question primarily is what does it actually mean to say that C encloses the region D? I have an intuitive geometric idea of what this is supposed to mean, but how would you rigorously define what this means in something like Real Analysis? Especially if we move up from curves enclosing 2D regions, to some 3D manifold enclosing a 4D region, where there is no way to actually visualize what is going on.

Comment: I gues finding a way to explicitly talk about the interior is the main problem in proving Jordan's Curve theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). So there is in general no explicity way.

Comment: I was just about to link that too. It is actually a lot more complicated then one would think, and it took a long while for the Jordan Curve Theorem to be proven.

Comment: Nota also that Green's theorem is a special case of Stokes' theorem, where $D$ is a surface in 3D with boundary $C$. Here, a curve $C$ can be the boundary of many $D$s, and you'll be looking at homology.

Comment: @epiliam right, its intuitively obvious, but very hard. In a way, it's so obviou that you don't know where to even start with a proof.

Comment: @Toffomat I feel like that is the case with a lot of things in math. For instance, provided you understand what a transcendental number is, the fact that pi is one seems pretty intuitive, but to actually prove that is an absolute nightmare. And then you have cases such as in geometry where it seems completely obvious that the parallel postulate should be true but it turns out to be an apriori assumption you have to impose upon the geometric theory.

Comment: Not a full answer, but if the boundary is differentiable, you could say something that involves any point in the interior being on the normal of some point on the boundary. Ofc this seems hard to define. Dang, never realized how difficult it was trying to explicitly talk about the interior of a curve.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question since it's a bit of a cheat. Let $B$ be a simple closed curve and $D$ be the set of points in "inside" $B$. How do we explicitly define $D$. Well one cheat is to first find a point $d \in D$. Then say that any curve that contains $d$ and doesn't contain any point in $B$ is itself in $D$. There's your explicit definition. Of course, this is cheating since I never proved that $d \in D$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

$$\{x\in \mathbb R^2\setminus C:\text{there is no continous}\,\gamma:[0,1]\to  \mathbb R^2\setminus C\,\text{with}\,\gamma(0)=x\, \text{and}\,\|\gamma(1)\|>\max_{c\in C}\|c\|\}$$

If you want the boundary to belong to your set just add $C$.

This definition captures the intuitive fact, that a point inside the curve cannot be joint to a point outside the curve without crossing the curve.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Though I'm not sure I quite understand the notation. What does R^2 \ C mean? and what is the max(c in C) mean?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2\setminus C$ is the set of all points in the plane which do not belong to $C$. $R=\max_{c\in C}\|c\|$ is the greatest distance from a point of $C$ to the origin, so $R$ is the smallest radius of a circle centered at the origin which fully contains $C$. The point is that any two points outside this circle of radius $R$ can be joint by a curve not intersecting $C$, thus any point $x$ with $\\|x\|>R$ lies on the outside.